# Calculating statistical significance between dependent Spearman coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, spearman-rho

I have a set of scores on a specific dataset given by human evaluators, let's call it `HJ`. I also have the scores of two computer models on the **same** dataset, let's call these sets `M1` and `M2`. I have calculated Spearman's coefficients for `(HJ,M1)` and `(HJ,M2)`, which show that `M2` is closer to human judgements than `M1`. Now I've been asked to find out if the **difference** between these two rho coefficients is statistically significant. My statistical knowledge is limited, so any help on how I could do that would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

In the book "Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioural Sciences" (Cohen and Cohen, 1975), I found the following $t$-statistic formula for cases identical to the one I describe above, but for *Pearson* coefficients:

$$
t=\frac{(r_{XY}-r_{VY})\sqrt{(n-3)(1+r_{XV})}}{\sqrt{2(1-r^2_{XY}-r^2_{VY}-r^2_{XV}+2r_{XY} r_{XV} r_{VY})}}
$$

where $r_{XY}$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ and $n$ is the sample size. Is this also applicable to rank correlations? For a 2-tailed $t$-test it gives different results than the permutation test suggested by Greg below (in case I ask something trivial please excuse my ignorance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is a permutation test.  You would randomly swap within M1,M2 pairs then recompute the difference in the 2 correlations.  Repeate that a bunch of times, then compare where your original difference lies compared to the permuted differences.  Here is some R code to demonstrate:

```
> orig <- with(iris, cor(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, method='s') - 
+ cor(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, method='s') )
> 
> out <- replicate(999, {tmp <- rbinom(nrow(iris), 1, 0.5);
+ cor( iris$Sepal.Length, ifelse(tmp, iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width), method='s') -
+ cor( iris$Sepal.Length, ifelse(tmp, iris$Petal.Width, iris$Petal.Length), method='s')
+ })
> 
> out <- c(orig,out)
> hist(out)
> abline(v=orig, col='red')
> mean(  out >= orig )
[1] 0.239
> mean( abs(out) >= orig )
[1] 0.486
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Let me see if I understood well. If `M1=[m1,m2,m3,m4]` and `M2=[k1,k2,k3,k4]`, a permutation of this could be e.g. `[k1,m2,m3,k4]` and `[m1,k2,k3,m4]`? (I mean, the indices must always match, right?) Then we calculate rho for each one of those permuted sets with `HJ` set and we record the difference. Finally we calculate the percentage of those differences that are higher or equal to the original difference `rho(HJ,M1)-rho(HJ,M2)`, which is our (one-sided) p-value. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct.  Since the ultimate distribution is symetric (for every permutation you can switch everything and get the negative of the difference you computed) the 2-tailed test (compare absolute values) is probably more meaningful.